# Need help in understanding circuit of PMOS reverse

Tags: transistors, mosfet, cmos, homework, reverse-polarity

[image]

Given 2 PMOS enhancement: Vdd = 5 V, k1/k2 = 9, Vt = -1.

I'm trying to find Voh, Vol, Vil, Vih.

I would appreciate help and explanation.

Comment: Welcome! Is this homework? What have you tried to far and where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi, thank you. Yes, it's homework. I can't understand and solve. I will write the question more clearly:
Inverter given two PMOS Enhancement transistors. 
VDD = 5v, Vt = -1V, Kp1 /Kp2 = 9 , Kp =1/2 pCox(W/L). 

I try to find VOH, VOL, VIH, VIL, VM

I don't know how the circuit works for pmos? Is P1 always in saturation?

Comment: Please write the expression for when P1 is in saturation. Is it fulfilled in the scenario you have?

Comment: ... and edit the information into the question. Don't bury it in the comments.